# Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, centos, java-home

On executing `sudo ./startup.sh` in CentOS, I am getting the following error:

> "Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is
>   defined"

But I have already defined it in bashrc in the following way:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/manish/New_learning/jdk1.8.0_212
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: fyi, that leaves the issue of `JRE_HOME` not being defined. What happens when you type `sudo echo $JAVA_HOME && sudo ./startup.sh` instead ? Do you see a path being show for the java folder ?

Comment: It does show path which I have added in bashrc file

Comment: I have tried without sudo but getting below error. ./startup.sh touch: cannot touch ‘/home/manish/New_learning/apache-tomcat-9.0.19-src/logs/catalina.out’: No such file or directory /home/manish/New_learning/apache-tomcat-9.0.19-src/bin/catalina.sh: line 464: /home/manish/New_learning/apache-tomcat-9.0.19-src/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

When you define it in your **.bashrc** file, it will be OK and well defined for your user.

When you launch the command with sudo, it runs as super-user/root, and NOT as your user; so your .bashrc file is 'useless' in this case.

You should update your environment with a system file like something under **/etc/profile.d** for instance:

```
sudo touch /etc/profile.d/variousPath.sh
sudo chown bsquare /etc/profile.d/variousPath.sh
cat >> /etc/profile.d/variousPath.sh <<EOF
export JAVA_HOME=/home/manish/New_learning/jdk1.8.0_212
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
EOF
```

Reboot your computer, and your SYSTEM environment will know `$JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: I have tried without sudo but getting below error. ./startup.sh

touch: cannot touch ‘/home/manish/New_learning/apache-tomcat-9.0.19-src/logs/catalina.out’: No such file or directory
/home/manish/New_learning/apache-tomcat-9.0.19-src/bin/catalina.sh: line 464: /home/manish/New_learning/apache-tomcat-9.0.19-src/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, because startup.sh script needs root privileges. So you must keep sudo BUT define your JRE/JDK variables somewhere else; I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Is it OK for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please Add in

> ../tomcat/bin/startup.sh

script with below java parameters syntax  :

`JAVA_HOME=/JDK/path/`

`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

`export PATH`

`export JAVA_HOME`

**Example**

> `JAVA_HOME=/appl/prod/Protine/tomcat/jdk1.5.0_16/`

> `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

> `export PATH`

> `export JAVA_HOME`

It's working for me , hope it will work for you too.